# How to display an Icon in a ListView subitem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, listviewitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set an icon for a ListViewSubItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888542/how-can-i-set-an-icon-for-a-listviewsubitem)

How to display an Icon in a ListView subitem

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get that is by using [owner draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx).  Use Graphics.DrawIcon in your DrawSubItem event handler.