# How to add an image in listview.subitem

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to know how to add image in list view sub item.

I am using this code to display text in the sub item.

```
 double Text = "2452";
 ListViewItem lItem = new ListViewItem();
 lItem.SubItems.Add(Text.ToString());
```

I want to do something like this

```
 ListViewItem lItem = new ListViewItem();
 lItem.SubItems.Add(Text.ToString() + "C:\\image.png");
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set an icon for a ListViewSubItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888542/how-can-i-set-an-icon-for-a-listviewsubitem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListView does not support this.

I found another answer, suggesting that you switch it with DataGridView.

[How can I set an icon for a ListViewSubItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888542/how-can-i-set-an-icon-for-a-listviewsubitem)

You could of course, do custom painting of the ListView if you wish, but I must say that things will get very complicated this way.

Comment: can u say me how can i just add a image in list view item like this lItem.SubItems.Add("C:\\test.png"); . i am new in c#

Comment: You can only set icon for the ListViewItem in .Net, not the SubItems. Take a look at the other question I found, they have lots of solutions for this problem already. =)

Answer (score 12):

```
private void ListView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e) {
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void ListView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e) {
    if (!(e.Item.SubItems(0) == e.SubItem)) {
        e.DrawDefault = false;
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.Image1, e.SubItem.Bounds.Location);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font, new SolidBrush(e.SubItem.ForeColor), (e.SubItem.Bounds.Location.X + My.Resources.Image1.Width), e.SubItem.Bounds.Location.Y);
    }
    else {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do this by implementing your own HttpHandler for the image. This is a .ashx file that implements the IHttpHandler interface.

So if you built one called ImageHandler you could use it declaratively in your ListView, something like this:

```
<asp:ListView 
     ID="ImageListView" 
     runat="server"
     DataKeyNames="Id">
        <ItemTemplate>        
            <img id="img1" src='<%#"~/ImageHandler.ashx?Id=" + Eval("Id") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```